# NuGet Packages returns `Illegal characters in path.` on install

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I created a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NC.Frontend.Env/), it's a fork from an already existing but dead [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NougatUI/).

I removed two folders that we did not use anymore. Due to them being too long for the windows limit on 260 chars.

When I try to install the new package via the GUI in VS2012 it fails and returns

> Illegal characters in path.

When I try the Package Manager Console I get the following error:

```
PM> Install-Package NC.Frontend.Env
Installing 'NC.Frontend.Env 1.0.1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package NC.Frontend.Env
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I also tried `nuget install NC.Frontend.Env -Verbosity detailed` but not much more is exposed:

```
GET http://nuget.episerver.com/feed/packages.svc/FindPackagesById()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&$orderby=Version desc&$top=1&id='NC.Frontend.Env'
GET http://nuget.episerver.com/feed/packages.svc/FindPackagesById()?id='NC.Frontend.Env'
GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&$orderby=Version desc&$top=1&id='NC.Frontend.Env'
GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='NC.Frontend.Env',Version='1.0.1')
nuget : System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:2
+  nuget install NC.Frontend.Env -Verbosity detailed
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System.Argument...acters in path.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
   at System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(String path)
   at NuGet.ZipPackage.IsPackageFile(PackagePart part)
   at NuGet
.OptimizedZipPackage.<EnsurePackageFiles>b__9(PackagePart part)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at NuGet.OptimizedZipPackage.EnsurePackageFiles()
   at NuGet.OptimizedZipPackage.GetAssemblyReferencesCore()
   at NuGet.LocalPackage.get_AssemblyReferences()
   at NuGet.DataServicePackage.get_AssemblyReferences()
   at NuGet.PackageExtensions.HasProjectContent(IPackage package)
   at NuGet.PackageWalker.GetPackageTarget(IPackage package)
   at NuGet.PackageWalker.GetPackageInfo(IPackage package)
   at NuGet.PackageWalker.ProcessPackageTarget(IPackage package)
   at NuGet.PackageWalker.Walk(IPackage package)
   at NuGet.InstallWalker.ResolveOperations(IPackage package)
   at NuGet.PackageManager.Execute(IPackage package, IPackageOperationResolver resolver)
   at NuGet.PackageManager.InstallPackage(IPackage package, FrameworkName targetFramework, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions, Boolean ignoreWalkInfo)
   at NuGet.PackageManager.InstallPackage(IPackage package, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions)
   at NuGet.PackageManager.InstallPackage(String packageId, SemanticVersion version, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions)
   at NuGet.Commands.InstallCommand.InstallPackage(IFileSystem fileSystem, String packageId, SemanticVersion version)
   at NuGet.Commands.InstallCommand.ExecuteCommand()
   at NuGet.Commands.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I have no idea why this is happening, and it seems strange as I only removed stuff.

Comment: Well, show us what files are stored in the .zip archive.  That's what it is complaining about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have long paths in your package. I managed to install your package only if my project folder is at root :

[image: successful install]

Otherwise I get a long path error :

[image: long path error]

Maybe you should consider using a classic install or a vsix for tooling, and nuget only for direct project dependencies ? Or maybe split the tooling in parts ? There are already packages for node and npm :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Node.js/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npm/

Comment: I fixed my issue, but I can't close it myself yet. I was using the GUI tool, using the cmd tool fixed my issue. The issue with the long paths should be fix, or I attempted to fix it by flattening the node_modules folder.

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen You could write your own answer with your fix to close the question, maybe it could help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was due to the tool I used.

I was using the GUI tool, but when I used the Command Line tool everything worked perfectly.

Comment: this should not be an accepted answer as it does not fix the issue